# Update stack on aws cloudFormation - error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation

I created a stack on CloudFormation with this file :

**test.yaml**

```
Resources:
  MyS3Bucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Properties:
      BucketName: 'myclf-2'
```

I updated the property of the resource by adding the accessControl to PublicRead; in another .yaml file

**test2.yaml**

```
  MyS3Bucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Properties:
      BucketName: 'myclf-2'
      AccessControl: PublicRead
```

When I upload the second file (test2.yaml) to update the stack, i had this error:

> The bucket does not allow ACLs (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 400; Error Code: AccessControlListNotSupported; Request ID: xxxxx; S3 Extended Request ID: yyyy; Proxy: null)

I resolve it by :

- In the permission tab on the bucket page : Block all public access - off
- I enalbled the ACLs : [https://aws.plainenglish.io/s3-error-accesscontrollistnotsupported-358cc5b27e15][1]

Is it a good idea to resolve it like that and after to put at **On** the option **Block all public access** in the permission tab of the bucket ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it a good idea to resolve it like that and after to put at On the option Block all public access in the permission tab of the bucket ?

No. If you enable enable all Block all public access, then you will not have public access anyway. Instead you should enable everything back, except [IgnorePublicAcls](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/access-control-block-public-access.html#access-control-block-public-access-options) which is going to allow you for existing public access on the bucket.